# 2010 Jeep Compass randomly blows the horn

Tags: jeep, horn, compass

The jeep does not have to be running to do it either. Parked at work, home or anywhere. It also does it driving down the road. Sometimes short burst and sometimes really long ones. What causes this and what can I do to stop it. It is very aggravating especially when your are at a stop light next to a cop or some hot head thinks you are blowing at them to go and they give you the HI sign.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: While nothing concrete, it seems the clockspring may be at fault. The clockspring is under the airbag in the steering wheel. It allows there to be connections for the horn even when the steering wheel goes round-n-round. It may be grounding out. The only way to tell is by removing the airbag and checking the clockspring itself. Not something I'd suggest for the uninitiated, as the steering wheel airbag, if not tended to correctly, can blow up in your face ... *literally*.

Comment: Try disconnecting the horn connection to the steering wheel and see if the behavior changes. If it does get the steering wheel assembly looked at. If no change then there must be a short somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you !!! I unplugged the horn and it has not done it since. Thanks for the help.